# Need to mix dynamic SQL, Open Query, JSON, dynamic variables, and a few other oddities into a single query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, for-json

Need to run dynamic SQL against DB2 on MS SQL through OpenQuery, get results back in JSON, then return this as an Output Parameter in a Stored Procedure

I've tried using a table variable as the sample code shows, but I get this error:

> The FOR JSON clause is not allowed in a INSERT statement

I've also tried wrapping the query into a CTE, but given the JSON column name changes I can't use * or I get this error:

> No column name was specified for column 1 of 'tbl'.

So I'm at a loss. I need to run this and get the JSON in the Output parameter, but given I'm having to mix a call to DB2 through OpenQuery and dynamic SQL to set the parameter I can't find a syntax that works.

```
create procedure uspTesting (
    @inAccountNumber nvarchar(20), 
    @outJSON nvarchar(max) output)
as
begin declare @result table (ResultJson nvarchar(max));

    declare @tsql nvarchar(4000) = '
    select name, age
    from  openquery(db2link,''
        select  name, 
                age 
        from    db2.account 
        where   accountnumber = ''''' + @inAccountNumber + ''''')'') tbl for json auto';

    insert into @result
    EXEC (@TSQL);

    select @outJSON = ResultJson from @result; End
```

The results I'm looking for are the JSON string in the output parameter @outJSON.

Comment: Maybe do your insert into a temp table or table variable, then select from that temp table with for json to return the json back out.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the FOR JSON after you've gotten the data, load it into a temp table and then use the FOR JSON.

Without test data, etc you might have to adjust this, but try something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [uspTesting]
    (
        @inAccountNumber NVARCHAR(20)
      , @outJSON NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
    )
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @result TABLE
            (
                [name] NVARCHAR(100) --whatever data type you need here
              , [age] NVARCHAR(100)
            );

        DECLARE @tsql NVARCHAR(4000) = '
    select name, age
    from  openquery(db2link,''
        select  name, 
                age 
        from    db2.account 
        where   accountnumber = ''' + @inAccountNumber + ''')';

        --Here we will just load a table variable with the data.
        INSERT INTO @result
        EXEC ( @tsql );

        --Then we will select from that table variable applying the JSON here.
        SET @outJSON = (
                           SELECT *
                           FROM   @result
                           FOR JSON AUTO
                       );

    END;
```